# Perl split string at character entity reference &nbsp;

Tags: perl, encoding, character-entities, html-treebuilder

Quick Perl question with hopefully a simple answer. I'm trying to perform a split on a string containing non breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`). This is after reading in an `html` page using `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` and retrieving the string needed by `$titleString = $tree->findvalue('/html/head/title')`

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
$tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse_file( "filename" );
$titleString = $tree->findvalue('/html/head/title');
print "$titleString\n";
```

Pasted below is the original string and below that the string that gets printed:

```
Mr&nbsp;Dan Perkins&nbsp;(Active)
Mr?Dan Perkins?(Active)
```

I've tried splitting `$titleString` with `@parts = split('\?',$titleString);` and also with the original `nbsp`, though neither have worked. My hunch is that there's a simple piece of encoding code to be added somewhere?

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dan&nbsp;Perkins&nbsp;(Active)</title>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it `&nbsp` or `&nbsp;`? Those are different. Can you add the original website, or is that local?

Comment: Sorry it's a local html page, but I'll add the html to the question. It is `&nbsp;` - sorry didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to know how the text in the document is encoded. As such, `findvalue` returns an actual non-breaking space (U+00A0) when the document contains `&nbsp;`. As such, you'd use

```
split(/\xA0/, $title_string)
   -or-
split(/\x{00A0}/, $title_string)
   -or-
split(/\N{U+00A0}/, $title_string)
   -or-
split(/\N{NBSP}/, $title_string)
   -or-
split(/\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}/, $title_string)
```

Comment: Spot on. So is that the character encoding there? Many thanks.

Comment: NBSP is U+00A0. You could put an actual NBSP inside the pattern, but that would be unreadable. Best to use an escape as shown.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. Handy to know.